# blank reports on report viewer using c#

Tags: c#, reporting, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I have been searching the web but no to success.

My problem is when I view my report using c# the reportviewer is showing blank and doesn't even show the report logo or the design of the report.

I am using this code in my c#

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

DBconnection dbConString = new DBconnection(); //initialize connectDB with connection string
FbConnection dbConnect = new FbConnection(dbConString.getConnectionString()); // connect to database using connectdb

dbConnect.Open();

FbDataAdapter dbAdapter = new FbDataAdapter(Commandstring, dbConnect); // this is used in select query
DataTable dbDataTable = new DataTable(); // initiallization of table
dbAdapter.Fill(dbDataTable); // fills the table dtDataTable

ReportDataSource rprtDTSource = new ReportDataSource(dbDataTable.TableName, dbDataTable);

dbDataTable.TableName = "personnel_services";
this.Text = "Individual Personnel Service";

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "reports/" + "indi3" + ".rdl";

ReportParameter[] param = new ReportParameter[2];
param[0] = new ReportParameter("sigName", MainFrmManager.stbarEmpName.Text);
param[1] = new ReportParameter("positionName", MainFrmManager.stbarPosition.Text);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);

this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rprtDTSource);

this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
this.reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The web suggest to set

```
asyncrendering = false
```

but I can't find where to set that property. Can anyone teach me where to set the `asyncrendering` or any other solution?

I am using report builder 3 to create my reports with no reporting servers.

Comment: I would suspect that if you wrapped this in a try/catch block that you'll find that the viewer can't find the report. Have you stepped through this code with the debugger to verify what is and is not working?

Comment: yes i have used try catch but it doesn't show any error. my guess is there is a problem with asyncrendering but my problem where to set that? is it on the report builder or on c# itself I can't find it

Comment: Have you included report file .rdl or .rdlc in your project? Try adding the report source like this: `reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report1.rdlc";`